# Which port to use with socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Which port should I listen/emit on when using socket.io?

I was originally using 2053 with my SSL website, but found, after using the website in a school, that 2053 had been blocked.

So, is there a particular port I should use that is guaranteed not to be blocked?  Or should I assume it **could** be blocked?

Thanks.

Comment: We ll need more information about your server, is it in your control? Or do rent a server? Is it hosted with other website? Is socket.io also used to serve HTML?

Comment: It's a dedicated server and I have complete control.  The main website is Drupal, but I also run socket.io for a simple real-time game

Comment: If you have complete control, then you should be able to ensure the port isn t blocked, you may just have a over zealous AV or forgot to make a exception in your firewall. I doubt this is a programing problem.

Comment: It's blocked at the client end I mean, in the school, they block their outgoing port (2053), but I was wondering if there is a port they are unlikely to block...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you're using node.js to serve both your website and your socket.io connections, then you would typically use the same port for socket.io as you use for your web site (whateve port number that is).  Since most websites are servered on port 80 (http) or 443 (https), that's what you would use.  Since every webSocket connection (which is what socket.io is based on) starts with an http(s) request, they can share a port with your regular web requests and this is a central part of the webSocket design.  This also simplifies same origin request security in the browser since no cross origin header support is needed to connect to the same host/port as the web page came from.

For professionally hosted sites, you will probably have to refer to the instructions for using webSocket connections for your particular hosting company.  Because webSocket/socket.io connections are long lasting, they often require specific support in a typical hosting environment and may need to be done a particular way.  And, because the hosting company may be sharing infrastructure among many sites, you are often assigned specific ports which you can use and are not necessarily free to use just any port.

For your school-end of the connection, ports 80 and 443 will be open as long as the school allows browsing on the internet so those are your safest bets.

FYI, the site http://portquiz.net/ is listening for http requests on all ports so you can test any port you want with it.

Comment: Whenever I try and listen on 443 the process just exits - i.e. I output 'listening on port...' in the callback function for listen, but it's never reached, the script just exits...

Comment: @lombrozo - There is probably an error code from `.createServer()` or from `.listen()` that will tell you why it fails.

Comment: @lombrozo - See the last paragraph I added to my answer for a way to test which ports are open for outbound connections from your school network.

Comment: Any way to do this on the fly - determine what ports are open using Javascript or something like that?

Comment: @lombrozo - Various options discussed in this thread: http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/searching-for-outbound-port-scan-utility.99373/.  If you have a specific server on a specific port that you want to test and that server is enabled for cross origin browser access, one could also write a quick test for that port from a browser too.